# Is it possible to get ASCII equivalent of UTF-8 characters?

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, ascii

I have extracted text from a PDF using PyMuPDF and certain characters appear to be Unicode instead of ASCII, which is annoying. For example, U+201D instead of U+0022 or U+2019 instead of U+0027. I want the ASCII codes and one way that I have thought about this is by using regex substitution or something similar. Is there a way that I could change these to their ASCII counterparts?

More visual examples:
[image: More visual example]

Comment: So you want to convert Unicode to ASCII???

Comment: Why is it annoying?  You certainly can do `s.replace("\u201d",'"')`

Comment: @TimRoberts Sure, that handles a single character value. I think the OP is looking for a general way of translating Unicode text to ASCII. Any such translation is going to lose information (if the result is expected to be legible).

Comment: He needs exactly 4 translations.  I didn't include them all, because I was pretty sure he could provides the others.  There is no generic "Unicode text to ASCII" translation.  This is a specific need for 4 specific characters.

Comment: @TimRoberts He said those were *examples*. If those are the only 4 characters he wants to translate, then of course it's trivial. If they really are just examples, the problem can be arbitrary difficult to solve.